# SQL Server stemming issue for dutch language

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, stemming

I use following code to get variations of a dutch word. It works correctly in SQL Server 2008 but SQL Server 2012.

```
SELECT display_term 
FROM sys.dm_fts_parser(N'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, "gespecialiseerd ")', 1043, 0, 1)
```

So I researched about it and applied this instruction: http://docs.ixperion.smartsite.nl/?nr=56830

The problem is fixed for Dutch but I started getting errors for Turkish Language when I run this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Englishturkish WHERE contains(turkish,'FORMSOF( INFLECTIONAL, "sel")')
```

The error says:

> An error has occurred during the full-text query.
>   Common causes include: word-breaking errors or timeout, FDHOST permissions/ACL issues, service account missing privileges, malfunctioning IFilters, communication channel issues with FDHost and sqlservr.exe, etc.

Then I repaired SQL Server, it didn't work. Then I removed SQL Server and installed SQL Server 2014 Turkish works now but still Dutch issue exist.

Please help.